# Regular expression for printing integers within brackets

Tags: python, regex

First time ever using regular expressions and can't get it working although there's quite a few examples in stackoverflow already.

How can I extract integers which are in a string inside bracket?

Example:

```
dijdi[d43]     d5[55++][ 43]  [+32]dm dij [    -99]x
```

would return

```
[43, 32, -99]
```

`'+'` and `'-'` is okay, if it's in the beginning of the brackets, but not okay if it's in the middle or end. If the `'+'` sign is in the beginning, it should not be taken into account. `(+54 --> 54)`

Been trying :

```
re.findall('\[[-]?\d+\]',str)
```

but it's not working the way I want.

Comment: Maybe `\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*]`? See https://regex101.com/r/8d8DDt/1

Comment: of course you have to escape the ] to get it working.

Comment: @ruud `[` is escaped, the formatting does not show it

Comment: Could there be case like `[   +-33]` or `[  -+44]` and if so, what is excepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to fail the match in `[ +-34 ]` (i.e. if you needn't extract a negative number if there is a `+` before it) you will need to use

```
\[\s*(?:\+|(-))?(\d+)\s*]
```

and when getting a match, concat the Group 1 and Group 2 values. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8d8DDt/2).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\+?` - an optional `+` char
- `(-?\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (the actual output of `re.findall`): an optional `-` and 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `]` -  a `]` char.

In Python,

```
import re
text = "dijdi[d43]     d5[55++][ 43]  [+32]dm dij [    -99]x"
numbers_text = [f"{x}{y}" for x, y in re.findall(r'\[\s*(?:\+|(-))?(\d+)\s*]', text)]
numbers = list(map(int, numbers_text))

# => [43, 32, -99] for both
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract integers from a string the code that I use is this:

```
def stringToNumber(inputStr):
myNumberList = []
for s in inputStr.split():
    newString = ''.join(i for i in s if i.isdigit())
    if (len(newString) != 0):
        myNumberList.append(newString)
return myNumberList
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've not done so I suggest you switch to the [PyPI regex module](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-python.html). Using it here with `regex.findall` and the following regular expression allows you to extract just what you need.

```
r'\[ *\+?\K-?\d+(?= *\])'
```

[regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/cC3hY7/156) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](https://repl.it/@CarySwoveland/SecondhandMaroonIntegrationtesting-1)

At the regex tester pass your cursor across the regex for details about individual tokens.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\[       : match '['
\ *      : match 0+ spaces
\+?      : optionally match '+'
\K       : forget everything matched so far and reset
           start of match to current position
-?       : optionally match '-'
\d+      : match 1+ digits
(?= *\]) : use positive lookahead to assert the last digit
         : matched is followed by 0+ spaces then ']'
```